# KVO Unexpected Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView whose **height** changes at runtime : the app loads images and then displays them in the TableView. I've implemented a pull to refresh like feature for the **footer** of my tableview.

Since height of the rows is not constant, I have added an observer on my UITableView:

```
[self.tableView addObserver:_refreshFooter
                 forKeyPath:@"contentSize"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:NULL];
```

In my **_refreshFooter**, the following method is called as soon as the contentSize changes :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
  UITableView *tbV = object;

  float realBottom = MAX(tbV.frame.size.height, tbV.contentSize.height);
  self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                          realBottom,
                          self.frame.size.width,
                          self.frame.size.height);
}
```

The app is basically a tabbar app where each tab is an instance of the TableViewController.
On our iPhone 4 and 4S in 5.0.1 and 5.1, we have never experienced any crashes due to KVO but our users tells us unexpected behaviour such as the footer not being moved or crash.

The crash experienced is the following :

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3671bf78 objc_msgSend + 15
1   Foundation 0x31145659 NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 68
2   Foundation 0x3113774b NSKeyValueWillChange + 414
3   Foundation 0x3110e84f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 182
4   Foundation 0x31190b23 _NSSetSizeValueAndNotify + 82
5   UIKit 0x32368f8d -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateContentSize] + 572
6   UIKit 0x3249cd51 -[UITableView setTableFooterView:] + 432
```

Comment: where you are removing this observer?

Comment: In viewDidUnload in my UITableViewController but it's never called since the viewControllers does not need to be unload during runtime

Comment: you need to release that in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: And add the observer again in viewWillAppear? I can't reproduce the issue so  I can't tell if it will happen again!

Comment: Add observer only in viewWillAppear, currently are you adding this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I added it in my getter through lasy instanciation but now I moved it in viewWillAppear

Comment: check now and see whether it fix your issue?

Comment: I can't say, the issue happens only to our users and we've never been able to reproduce it!

Comment: this is fix your issue, because with out removing observer, if some call goes when view is not in focus, then that will definitely cause the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` in `viewWillDisapper` and add this is `viewWillAppear`.